# How to make foreground objects mask out the background, while not being rendered?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-layers

Let's say I have a character and some columns in the foreground. I need to render (eevee) only the character in such a way that if he goes behind the column he is erased by its shape (disappear behind it), and if he is walking in front of the column I can see him. But the column itself is not rendered. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can define the columns as holdouts.

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: glad i could help! you are welcome!